# Ansible SSH Proxy "Error reading SSH protocol banner"

Tags: ansible

When using an ssh proxy and the netwrok_cli connection method, I've been getting a "Error reading SSH protocol banner" error in Ansible.

Seems like it may be the banner_timeout setting, which I can set if I write a netmiko script and it works but I don't think I can set that in a playbook.

This is what the playbook looks like:

```
- name: playbook
  hosts: target_dev_hostname
  gather_facts: no
  connection: network_cli
  vars:
    ansible_user: username
    ansible_ssh_pass: password
    ansible_become_pass: password
    ansible_network_os: ios

  tasks:   
  - name: set mode for private key
    file:
      path: jump_host.pem
      mode: 0400
    delegate_to: localhost

  - name: config proxy
    set_fact:
      ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /jump_host.pem -W %h:%p -q jump_user@jump_host.me.com"'
    delegate_to: localhost

  - name: basic show run
    ios_command:
      commands: show run
    register: running_config

  - name: show run results
    debug: var=running_config
```

Any suggestions? Seems like this issue has been popping up in Ansible since about last year.... found this issue being reported:
https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.netcommon/issues/46

I should add, this same playbook works in Ansible 2.5.1

Comment: try an ansible ping to the host, with -vvvvv and to see what's going on, assuming this works on ios. `ansible HOST -i INVENTORY -m ping -vvvvv`

Comment: @G_G, I can ping the jump box so it doesn't look like it's a reachability issue.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. After upgrading to the latest Abnibble and Paramiko, none of my playbooks that use a jump host work anymore. I always get the same "Error reading SSH protocol banner".